# How can i fill in export column with value that sum(export)=TotalExport

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table like this. But `totalExport` is no column in my table.
[Fill value column sql or c#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eha2C.png)

```
id  code    import  export  inventory       TotalExprt
1   MA01    200     200     400              600
2   MA01    300     300     100              
3   MA01    150     ...     ...              
4   MA01    100     ...     ...              
5   MA02    100     100                      550
6   MA02    100     100                      
7   MA02    350     350
```

I must fill `export` column with the value equals `import` column, and when i sum `export` column, this must equals `TotalExport` value.
Anyhelp pls.

Many tks !

Comment: Please explain how you calculate the `TotalExport`.  You have tag the `c#`, but you didn't mention how this question related to (e.g. code? how it display?).  From your screen cap, it's not clear to us how you build the result.  Last and important thing, please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Yeah...It's not clear, please provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These don't match the results you are expecting, but if I understand your problem correctly, I think this is what you want:

```
with cte as (
  select code, sum (export) as total
  from totalExport
  where export is not null
  group by code
)
update totalExport
set
  TotalExport = cte.total
from cte
where
  totalExport.code = cte.code
```

If you don't actually need to update the values and can have them in a query, an analytic/windowing function would do the trick:

```
select
  code, export, sum (export) over (partition by code)
from totalExport
```

Comment: Sr.. My english it very bad. But my bro was help me a hour before. 
He use function "partition" in sql , that  

select TotalExport - sum(import) over (partition by code order by id) as sumEx

I can't understand it, but i see, that is all what i need.  Thank for your help. Many thank !

Comment: Your English is better than my <your language>, so don't feel bad.  Was this MS SQL Server or some other RDBMS?  It would help to tag that on the question and any future ones you may have.  Different DBMSs will or won't support various features, such as windowing functions used in the example above.

Comment: Thank for your instruction for me. This is a first time i am post a question, so pls forgive me. Thank you verymuch. And this is MS SQL Server. I'm was leave some tags in last post.